# Поиск дубликата записей в таблице SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Есть таблица с несколькими полями. Есть список id, к которым нужно найти дубликаты по 3 полям (поле 1, поле 2, поле 3).

Например, у меня есть id 1 - соответственно запрос должен вернуть id 5 и id 10 (совпадают первые 3 поля);для id 3 вернет id 7 (также совпадают 3 поля), для остальных id ничего не вернет (нет совпадений по 3 полям).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу составить запрос, который вывод бы только дубликаты (или исходная строка + дубликат) на основе id, прошу помочь.

Все дубликаты в таблице выводить умею, количество считаю тоже, а вот дубликаты к конкретным записям не могу найти.

Естественно, "боевая" таблица в разы больше :) Нужно понять принцип.

Comment: Join двух копий таблицы по полям сравнения и отбором по заданному критерию.

Comment: Row_number с партишеном по этим 3 полям,

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста брэнд БД. Неужели "боевая" таблица в четырёх БД? И дайте пример данных не картинкой, а  текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте оконные функции.

```
With data as (
  Select
   *,
   row_number() over (partition by [Поле1],[Поле2],[Поле3] order by id) as rowNumber 
  from table 
)
Select
  * 
from data 
where
 rowNumber > 1
```

Пример с rank фильтровать id

```
With data as (
  Select
   *,
   row_number() over (partition by [Поле1],[Поле2],[Поле3] order by id) as rowNumber,
  Rank() over (partition by [Поле1],[Поле2],[Поле3] order by id) as rowRank 
  from table 
)
Select
  * 
from data
 Inner join data as data1
    On data.rowRank = data1.rowRank and data.id <> data1.id
where
 Data1.rowNumber > 1 and data.id in (надо указать список id который нужно отфильтровать)
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если нужно искать дубли к конкретным id, как построить запрос?

Comment: Функция row_number каждый раз начинает отсчёт на новых партишенах. Если вам нужны дубликаты то тупо делаете партишен по этому полю(ям).

Comment: Я понял. Просто у меня много комбинаций разных в пределах 3 полей и нужно для всего списка ID прогнать поиск дублей по 3 полям. Не могли бы показать как это сделать?

Comment: Да тогда дополнительно нужно использовать Rank либо Dense_rank. Они также пронумеруют группу. Т.е по факту вы также получите ранк группы.

Comment: Далее соединив ее саму на себя по рангу и отфильтрованы нужные ид можно получить дубликаты

Comment: Большое спасибо! А не могли бы показать на конкретном примере как для этого использовать Rank. А то никогда не пользовался подобными функциями ранее.

Comment: Как то так далее напильником

Comment: А нет ли более простого решения? 

Например, я указываю id, указываю поля по которым искать дубликаты и он выдает список аналогичных строк?

А-то как-то слишком сложно. Указанный код у меня почему-то заполнил таблицу копиями строки, которую ввел в IN. Как я понимаю, там должен был быть всё же диапазон, а не id, для которого ищем дубликаты. Но мой диапазон - вся таблица.

Comment: Диапазон немного увеличит вывод :). А вот указываю поля по которым искать это уже динамическим запросом попахивает.

Comment: Почему? Если у меня есть заранее указанный список id, полученный другим запросом или подзапросом

Comment: Вы хотите выбирать поля для группировки. Это динамика если точно не указать какие. Идёт соединение по рангу а если к примеру записей 4 то в одной группе то результат станет 9 когда нужно всего 3

Comment: Aziz Umarov, у Вас отличное решение с window function, тоже солидарна с Вами ) голосую

Comment: А если точно указать поля?

Comment: Если точно указывать то пользуйтесь вторым вариантом,  единственно нужно смотреть и выкидывать излишки за счёт id который в диапазоне

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where id not in
(select max(id) id from table group by поле1, поле2, поле3 having count(*)=1)
```

Comment: Да согласен, проще вариант. Но если задавать поля то все равно будет динамика. Но всё же проще.

Comment: Тогда лучше вынести в CTE и соединить на left join и убрать соединившиеся

Comment: Но в задании было поиск дубликатов за минус оригинала, у вас оригинал тоже вернет

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]